# Integrating neural net with Django

Tags: django, asynchronous, neural-network

I have a sync Django setup, but want to be able to serve neural net predictions.
The problem is that running NN prediction requires loading tensorflow library that takes super long to load every time (a few seconds), so this is not an option for every request.

I tried instantiating my NN model within a socket server and connecting to it from my django views, but this requires async-ing the entire Django setup. Also not what I want.

Is there a way to make these two play nicely together without too much overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [tensorflow/serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving). So you will make separate from Django server with your neural network and request it from your django views.